# ui-router dots in name not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The UI-Router docs shows that you can use dots in route name:

> ```
> <!-- partials/state1.html -->
> <h1>State 1</h1>
> <hr/>
> <a ui-sref="state1.list">Show List</a>
> <div ui-view></div>
> ```

But however in my app this doesn't work. This is an example that worked fine until I changed `client` to `client.ts` everywhere:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
    <title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="container">

  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" ui-sref="index">Quick Start</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="index">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="clien.ts">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="well" ui-view=""></div>        
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="well" ui-view="viewB"></div>        
    </div>
  </div>         

  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- UI-Router -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

  <!-- App Script -->
  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
    myapp.config(function($stateProvider){ 
    $stateProvider
        .state('index', {
            url: "",
            views: {
                "": {
                    template: "index.viewA-index"
                },
                "viewB": {
                    template: "index.viewB"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('route1', {
            url: "/route1",
            views: {
                "": {
                    template: "route1.viewA-route1"
                },
                "viewB": {
                    template: "route1.viewB"
                }
            }
        })
        .state('clien.ts', {
            url: "/clients",
            views: {
                "viewB": {
                    template: "clients.viewA-route2"
                },
                "": {
                    controller: function($scope, ClientService) {
                      console.log('Controller code being run');
                      $scope.clients = ClientService.clientList();
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'client-list-template.html'
                }
            }
        })
    })
    .service('ClientService',  function() {
      this.clientList = function() {
        clients = [{'name': 'Acme Food', 'description': 'Makers of fine food'},
                   {'name': 'Dog Biscuits Inc', 'description': 'Cruncy creations for canines'},
                   {'name': 'Parrot treats Ltd', 'description': 'Puveyors of bird food'},
                   {'name': 'Pond supplies', 'description': 'Sell fish and gravel'}];
        return(clients);
      }
    });
  </script> 

</body>

</html>
```

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZD7WlC9aKzpwte9dVMxC?p=preview

As you can see the link can't be clicked :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is add an abstract state for `clien` in that case.

Here's the plunkr, with the added state: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ftGbJ0gwhXbDTO5roCr6?p=preview)

Whenever you define states with the dot. You still need to at least define the abstract state for the child. In your case for `clien`.

**Also something from the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views)**

> If you register only a single state, like contacts.list, you MUST define a state called contacts at some point, or else no states will be registered. The state contacts.list will get queued until contacts is defined. You will not see any errors if you do this, so be careful that you define the parent in order for the child to get properly registered.

Comment: You don't even need the absolute states that I wrote there. But you still need to write the new `ui-view` elements where the childs can add the content. [Alternative plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MxWY1LNaZIsY3ItMJhYV?p=preview)

Comment: Damn, you beat me. That woulda been my plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/nf0yrnbEydmRH3Pfk6e6?p=preview ! No reason to use a sub-state if theres no parent for it ;-)

Comment: While your example works, the OP asked specifically why it doesn't work after he changes `clients` to `clien.ts`. He already knew that it was working without the dot.